# Application crash to start, when using BootReceiver

Tags: android, xml

I want my application to launch browser when boot my tablet but its crashing on boot time. If someone please let me know my mistake? I write nothing in my **activity_main.xmle**. Its showing me message "unfortunately the application crashed".

**mainfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.autostartmyapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    
        <receiver android:name=".BootReciever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>            
    </application>        
</manifest>
```

**mainActivitc class**

```
package com.example.autostartmyapp;    

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
    {    
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    }    
}
```

Comment: and what is your logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separate both classes and fix mainfest like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.autostartmyapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    
        <receiver
        android:name="com.example.autostartmyapp.BootReciever"
        android:enabled="true"         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>            
    </application>        
</manifest>
```

write MainActiity

```
MainActivity {
...}
```

BootReceiver class

```
package com.example.BootReciever;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent arg1) {

            Intent iMainActivity = new Intent(ctx, yourMainActivityClass);  
            iMainStartActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ctx.startActivity(iMainActivity);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say it's probably because your manifest specifies .BootReceiver as the receiver, but based on your code the BootReceiver class is nested inside MainActivity. So you either need to move BootReceiver to a top-level class, or change your manifest to specify .MainActivity.BootReceiver as the receiver.

If that doesn't resolve it, please post your logcat so we can see what error is causing the crash.

Comment: its doesn't work and logcat has no error. it runs fine normally but problem is when booting the tablet

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the Manifest as receiver section:

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".BootReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And take care of Broadcast Receiver class that should be not inner:

```
package com.example.BootReciever;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent arg1) {

            Intent iMainActivity = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);  
            iMainStartActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ctx.startActivity(iMainActivity);
    }



}
```

Comment: Do you mean no MainActivity is started at all?
Did you move BootReciever as a new class as I showed?

Comment: Yes I did it as you guys suggest... here is the code, can you please copy it and test by your self? Activity is not starting even.

http://hastebin.com/fedebesesu.xml

Answer (score -1):

Your app starts so quick and doesn't let other important apps to start first I think you should add some delay in your app to start up. like this:

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override

public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    // We can't wait on the main thread as it would be blocked if we wait for too long
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Lets wait some time before starting the service to be fair to other processes on startup
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Move your `BootReciever` to a new class and add this in your `manifast` :`<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootReciever" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">`

Comment: Yes I did it as you guys suggest... here is the code, can you please copy it and test by your self? Activity is not starting even.

http://hastebin.com/fedebesesu.xml